\fancyvrb with bolded text in Verbatim
Probably an easy answer, but I am stymied. I am trying to improve on Markdown and use the fancyvrb package to use both Verbatim text and some bolded commmands. I am trying to simplify the TeX commands for Markdown users.
In Markdown the following works just fine to bold commands:
::: code 
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\small,breaklines=true]
lab@desktop# \textbf{sample command}
\end{Verbatim}
:::

The string lab@desktop# appears as \texttt and sample command appears as \texttt and \textbf.
I am trying to remove all the TeX commands for users who do not understand LaTeX and are only semi-familiar with Markdown.
I am referencing a test.tex template file where I add the following:
%% test for bold verbatim
\newcommand{\boldverb}[1][commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\small,breaklines=true]{
    \begin{Verbatim}[#1]
    \end{Verbatim}
}

Then in my test Markdown file I attempt the following:
\boldverb{lab@desktop# \textbf{This is a sample bolded command}}

I use Pandoc to compile the file to PDF, but it fails with the following error:
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.1078 \boldverb{

I guess I am just dumb as I thought I added in the correct fields, but am simply missing something.
Any suggestions are most appreciated.

Please remove the tag tex-core

Sorry, but this is wrong under many respects. Main one: you cannot use Verbatim in the argument to a command.
Second issue, but very important: you're defining \boldverb with a single optional argument with a default value. Even if you could have Verbatim in the argument, your call would give
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\small,breaklines=true]
\end{Verbatim}
{lab@desktop# \textbf{This is a sample bolded command}}

and nothing would be inside the Verbatim environment.
However, the “obvious” change
\newcommand{\boldverb}[2][commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\small,breaklines=true]{
    \begin{Verbatim}[#1]
    #2
    \end{Verbatim}
}

wouldn't work, because the main issue comes into the scene.
Verbatim mode can only work as an environment at the top level. You can do
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{lVerbatim}{Verbatim}
  {commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\small,breaklines=true}

Proof of concept.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{courier}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{lVerbatim}{Verbatim}
  {commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\small,breaklines=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{lVerbatim}
lab@desktop# \textbf{This is a sample bolded command}
\end{lVerbatim}

\end{document}

I load courier because the default monospaced font hasn't boldface.


That worked perfectly. I chalk this up to my ignorance of LaTeX. I much appreciate your solution, and thanks!
